# Python+Selenium + element

Tags: python, selenium

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как искать по данному элементу?
Заранее благодарен.

lodengg@mail.ru

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса. // и вообще, ознакомьтесь, пожалуйста: [mcve]

Comment: пробовали XPath?

Comment: Подскажите как создать через XPath.если вы имеете ввиду просто скопирывать XPATH(мне это не подходит).